# ¿como puedo hacer push a 2 ramas distintas?

Tags: git, git-push, ramas-git

tengo una rama pruebas en mi local, esta rama la empujé al servidor remoto, asi que en el servidor remoto hay 2 ramas: Master y Pruebas. modifiqué un archivo, agregué el archivo al area de stage, hice un commit e hice push de ese conmmit a la rama Pruebas, ahora bien, esos cambios que hice tabien debo empujarlos a la rama Master. Mi intriga es: ¿ como lo hago? es decir, ya no tengo commit que empujar, como puedo hacer eso mismo que hice en la rama Pruebas? estoy algo confundido la verdad, recién comienzo con Git. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Como explicas, tienes cambios nuevos en la rama `pruebas` y estos debes llevarlo a `master` o viceversa. Para esto usas `merge`;

Para realizar el `merge` debes primero estar en la rama que quieres unir, en este caso digamos que estas en `pruebas` y quieres llevar esos cambios a `master`

```sh
git checkout master
```

Entonces ahora que estamos en master procedemos a realizar el `merge` en otras palabras, llevarnos los cambios de `pruebas` a `master`

```sh
git merge pruebas --no-ff
```

Con esto todos los cambios que realizamos se integraran a la rama `master`, si te fijas he agregado la bandera `--no-ff` la cual le indica a git que mantenga una topología de rama específica (con esto cuando leas el historial de cambios veras las lineas de las ramas).

[Mas sobre --no-ff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff)

Ver historial de cambios de todas las ramas de tu proyecto

```sh
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --all
```

Veras algo como esto;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para realizar el push basta con decirle

```sh
git push origin master
```

o

```sh
git push origin pruebas
```

Comment: ok, pero podria simplemente hacer un push a master en vez de hacer un merge? lo que no entiendo es porque mi compañero de equipo me dice que haga push a ambas ramas y no que push a una y luego merge con la otra, eso es lo que me confunde y no quiero cometer un error.

Comment: No puedes hacer un `push` desde `pruebas` a `master` sin hacer merge. (No que to conozca una forma). Se realiza el `push` a ambas ramas para mantener todos los cambios guardados en su repositorio remoto

Comment: No se puede porque son remas distintas ? entonces no entiendo por que me dice que debo hacer push a ambas ramas.

Comment: lo que el te dice es exactamente lo que te coloque de ejemplo donde menciono `git push origin master` y `git push origin pruebas` a eso el se refiere, si sigues las instrucciones que te he dado, dudo que cometas un error, de todas formas puedes experimentar en local sin hacer push

Comment: Ok, y no necesito tener un commit para hacer el push? cuándo hiceel push a Pruebas, tenía el archivo modificado y por eso hice un commit, al ahcer el push se subio con el commit.

Comment: Si, necesitas hacer `commit` antes de `push` o `merge` estos dos ultimos los puedes hacer en el orden que queiras. Si necesitas mas información sobre esto y el ciclo de git puedes leer mas en https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.es.html

Comment: leeré eso a ver xq sigo perdido. no puedo hacer un commit sin antes agregar arvhicos al stage, y no tengo archivos que agregar ya que la modficación ya la hice y lo que quiero es subir a master lo mismo que ya subí a Pruebas.

Comment: Lo que hice fue esto: git push origin pruebas:master , eso fue lo que el me dijo, estoy buscand donde explican eso, xq no lo entiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero te vas a git checkout master para dirigirte a la rama master luego de que estés en la rama master vas a hacer un git merge pruebas

Espero que esto te funcione.

Comment: Por que la persona con la que comparto el proyecto me dice que debo hacer push a Pruebas y Luego push a Master ? en ningún momento me habló de merge, la verdad estoy confundido.

Comment: Seguramente que tu no puedas hacer un merge...y solamente puedas hacer PUSH, es decir, que tengas el merge deshabilitado, lo que si podras hacer es solicitar un PULL REQUEST para que el encargado del caso hago un MERGE. Entonces te vas a una rama: por ejemplo, pruebas, haces el PUSH en esa rama, despues a MASTER haces el PUSH a esa rama y posteriormente solicitas el PULL REQUEST.

Comment: Ok, pero mi gran duda es.... para hacer un push debo tener cambios que agregar? cuando hice push a Pruebas, tenía un commit xq había modificado el archivo, Ahora...  en este momento lo que quiero subir a master es lo mismo que subí a pruebas, es de decir, no he hecho cambios y por lo tanto no tengo un commit, puedo hacer push a Master sin tener un commit?

Comment: Prueba realizando un pull a la rama master y verifica si los cambios se agregaron via el motodo fast-forward

Answer (score 0):

(vamos a suponer que usas github. El ejemplo es igual para gitlab, bitbucket, codecommit, etc)

Imaginemos que recién clonaste y pusiste:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit

> * A00001   commit en master
```

Estás parado en master en el commit A00001.

Ahora quieres crear una rama y hacer algunos cambios

```
$ git checkout -b Pruebas
$ echo 'hola' > hola.txt
$ git add hola.txt
$ git commit hola.txt -m "archivo nuevo de prueba"

> [Prueba B00002] "archivo nuevo de prueba"
> 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
> create mode 100644 hola.txt

$ git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit

> * B00002   archivo nuevo de prueba
> * A00001   commit en master
```

Para todo efecto, tu rama Prueba es simplemente `master` con un commit adicional

Pusheaste el commit B al remoto:

```
 $ git push --set-upstream origin Prueba

 * [new branch]      Prueba -> Prueba
 Branch 'Prueba' set up to track remote branch 'Prueba' from 'origin'.
```

Con eso el remoto quedó igual al local al menos en la rama `Pruebas`. Pero ahora tú quieres que el commit `B00002` quede en la rama `master` del remoto.

---

Hay más de una manera de hacer esto:

**1.- Al estilo salvaje (NO LO HAGAN)**

```
 $ git push origin Prueba:master
```

Es una mala idea. Si entre medio hubo commits en `master` no te va a aceptar el push. (A menos que uses el flag  `-f` que es aún más salvaje). Cualquier otro conflicto en el push no tienes cómo resolverlo con este approach y si te acepta el push tu rama local queda por detrás de la rama remota (aunque podrías moverte a master y hacer `git pull`).

**2.- Al estilo relajado**

Para proyectos personales no tiene nada de malo moverte a master, mergear `Prueba` y pushear

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge Prueba

> Updating A00001..B00002
  Fast-forward
  hola.txt | 1 +
  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git push

> To github.com:organizacion/repo
  A00001..B00002  master -> master
```

Ahora para todo efecto `master` piensa que su historial es lineal

```
$ git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit

> * B00002   archivo nuevo de prueba
> * A00001   commit en master
```

Él no sabe que alguna vez existió la rama `Prueba`

**3.- Al estilo organización**

En organizaciones (ya esa empresas, fundaciones, proyectos de código abierto) donde hay varios desarrolladores, trabajando en el mismo repo, en general se restringe el push directo a las ramas protegidas, y las ramas protegidas suelen ser `master` y `develop`.

Como no puedes simplemente pushear a master, lo que haces es crear un `pull request` (por ejemplo en github). Ese pull request puede mergearlo alguien con suficiente permiso, y puede que tú mismo lo tengas. La restricción de las ramas protegidas impide push directos, no impide pull requests dado que tengas el permiso para mergearlos.

Las ventajas de un Pull Request a priori son

1. Permite aislar la funcionalidad que añades (o el bug que reparas) en una unidad independiente de otras funcionalidades o bugfixes.
2. Si otro desarrollador aprueba los PR, te da otro par de ojos

Hay una tercera

Hecho el merge remoto y estando en `master` haces git pull

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull

> From github.com:organizacion/repo
  A00001..C00003  master      -> origin/master
  Updating  A00001..C00003
  Fast-forward
  hola.txt | 1 +
  1 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
  create mode 100644 hola.txt
```

Momento! Acá apareció un commit `C00003` que yo no hice! Veamos qué es

```
$ git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit

> * C00003   merge pull request #1 from organizacion/repo
> |\
> | * B00002   archivo nuevo de prueba
> |/
> * A00001   commit en master
```

Aquí queda de manifiesto que el flujo de un pull request, además los dos puntos anteriores, deja un commit (sin contenido sino como una marca) que dice: "En este punto se unió el pull request X a la rama". Cosa que no sería obvia mirando los commits, dado que el log de master sería una línea continua.

---